# How to dynamically create a subclass from a given class and enhance/augment the subclass constructor's prototype?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, mixins, subclassing

I have an unusual situation where I need to dynamically generate a class prototype then have a reflection tool (which can't be changed) walk the prototype and find all the methods. If I could hard code the methods, the class definition would look something like this:

```
class Calculator {
    constructor(name) { this.name = name; }
}
class AdditionCalculator extends Calculator {
    constructor(name) { super(name); }
    add(left, right) { console.log(this.name + (left + right)); }
}
class SubtractCalculator extends AdditionCalculator {
    constructor(name) { super(name); }
    subtract(left, right) { console.log(this.name + (left - right)); }
}
```

However, I can't hard code the methods/inheritance as I need a large number of combinations of methods that are data driven: For example, I need a Calculator with no math methods, a Calculator with Add() only, Calculator with Subtract() only, Calculator with Add() and Subtract(), and many more combos.

Is there any way to do this with JavaScript (I assume with prototypes)?

For reference, here's the reflection tool that finds the methods:

```
function getMethods(obj:object, deep:number = Infinity):Array<string> {
  let props:string[] = new Array<string>()
  type keyType = keyof typeof obj

  while (
    (obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) && // walk-up the prototype chain
    Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) && // not the the Object prototype methods (hasOwnProperty, etc...)
    deep !== 0
  ) {
    const propsAtCurrentDepth:string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
      .concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).map(s => s.toString()))
      .sort()
      .filter(
        (p:string, i:number, arr:string[]) =>
          typeof obj[<keyType>p] === 'function' && // only the methods
          p !== 'constructor' && // not the constructor
          (i == 0 || p !== arr[i - 1]) && // not overriding in this prototype
          props.indexOf(p) === -1 // not overridden in a child
      )
    props = props.concat(propsAtCurrentDepth)
    deep--
  }
  return props
}
```

For example: getMethods(new SubtractCalculator("name")); would return ["add", "subtract"]

Comment: How are those "combos" defined in your dynamic data? But basically all you need to do is create a new class that inherits from `Calculator` and then in a loop place all the methods on its `.prototype` that you want it to have.

Comment: @DoomGoober ... Is this question about vanilla script or exclusively TypeScript?

Comment: @PeterSeliger I'm using TypeScript but I reduced my example to vanilla to make them clearer. I realize the method finder function is TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could choose a composition and inheritance based approach where a factory-function creates a named subclass/subtype on-the-fly.

As for the OP's use case, one in addition, applies function-based mixin-composition in order to augment the subclass constructor's prototype. Thus, everything is covered by inheritance (the prototype chain), either directly via the subclass constructor's augmented prototype or via the further linked prototype of the base class.

The advantage of the entire approach comes with not having to write too much boilerplate (and repeating) code if it comes to the dynamic (or add-hoc) creation of `Calculator` based subclasses.

```js
// - factory function which implements dynamic sub-classing (or sub-typing).
// - the below implementation is generic, thus it not only allows/supports
//   the creation of named subclasses derived from the additionally provided
//   base class, but it also supports function-based mixin-composition at
//   both instance and class level.
function createNamedSubclassWithMixedInBehavior(
  className = 'UnnamedType' , baseClass = Object, mixinConfig = {}
) {
  const {
    compose: instanceLevelMixins = [],
    inherit: classLevelMixins = [],
  } = mixinConfig;

  const subClass = ({
    [className]: class extends baseClass {
      constructor(...args) {

        super(...args);

        instanceLevelMixins
          .forEach(behavior => behavior.call(this));
      }
    },
  })[className]; 

  classLevelMixins
    .forEach(behavior => behavior.call(subClass.prototype));

  return subClass;
}

// function-based mixins, each implementing a unique trait/behavior.
function withNegation() {
  this.negate = function negate (right) {
    return (-1 * right);
  }
}
function withAddition() {
  this.add = function add (left, right) {
    return (left + right);
  }
}
function withSubtraction() {
  this.subtract = function subtract (left, right) {
    return (left - right);
  }
}

// base `Calculator` class.
class Calculator {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

// a lookup based configuration of operator mixins.
const operatorMixins = {
  negation: [withNegation],
  addition: [withAddition],
  subtraction: [withSubtraction],
  negation_addition: [withNegation, withAddition],
  negation_subtraction: [withNegation, withSubtraction],
  addition_subtraction: [withAddition, withSubtraction],
  negation_addition_subtraction: [withNegation, withAddition, withSubtraction],  
};

// helpers for calculator instance logs.
function getConstructorName(value) {
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(value).constructor.name;
}
function getBaseConstructorName(value) {
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(value)).constructor.name;
}

// creation, access and logging of `Calculator` subclasses.
[
  ['negation', 'NegationType', 'negationOnly'],
  ['addition', 'AdditionType', 'addOnly'],
  ['subtraction', 'SubtractionType', 'subtractOnly'],

  ['negation_addition', 'NegationAdditionType', 'negateAndAdd'],
  ['negation_subtraction', 'NegationSubtractionType', 'negateAndSubtract'],
  ['addition_subtraction', 'AdditionSubtractionType', 'addAndSubtract'],

  ['negation_addition_subtraction', 'NegationAdditionSubtractionType', 'negateAndAddAndSubtract'],
]
.map(([operatorFlag, className, instanceName]) => [
  createNamedSubclassWithMixedInBehavior(
    className, Calculator, { inherit: operatorMixins[operatorFlag] }
  ),
  instanceName,
])
.forEach(([CalculatorSubClass, instanceName]) => {

  const calculatorSubType = new CalculatorSubClass(instanceName);

  console.log({
    instanceName: calculatorSubType.name,
    className: getConstructorName(calculatorSubType),
    baseClassName: getBaseConstructorName(calculatorSubType),
    negate: calculatorSubType.negate,
    add: calculatorSubType.add,
    subtract: calculatorSubType.subtract,
    "negate(-7)": calculatorSubType?.negate?.(-7),
    "add(1,14)": calculatorSubType?.add?.(1, 14),
    "subtract(19,10)": calculatorSubType?.subtract?.(19, 10),
  });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution (sorry about the switch to TypeScript):

```
let operatorNames:Array<string> = ["add", "negate"];
let root:object = new Calculator("someName");
for (let operatorFunctionName of operatorNames) {
  switch (operatorFunctionName) {
    case "add":
      let addPrototype = class AddClass {
        add(left:number, right:number) {
          console.log(this.name + " " + (left + right));
        }
      };
      Object.setPrototypeOf(addPrototype.prototype, root);
      root = new addPrototype();
      break;
    case "negate":
      let negatePrototype = class NegateClass {
        negate(right:number) {
          console.log(this.name + " " + (-right));
        }
      };
      Object.setPrototypeOf(negatePrototype.prototype, root);
      root = new negatePrototype();
      break;
  }
}
return root as Calculator;
```

We new up an instance of the base class, Calculator, which has no methods other than the constructor. Then we declare the derived class in local scope as a local variable (I tried doing it with global scope classes but then the classes were permanently changed.) Then, I set the local class prototype as having the instance of the base class as the prototype.

Then I instantiate the derived class and store that as the instance. Then repeat using the updated instance. In this way, I can dynamically keep adding derived classes on top of the derived classes.

Now, there's some hairiness here because the only way to call the Calculator constructor is manually before creating the derived class instance. I think I only have an *instance* of the derived class, not the derived class by itself (the derived class by itself couldn't be instantiated because the constructor for Calculator would not be called.) But that's OK, because all I needed was an instance of the derived class.

Calling getMethodNames(root) yields: ["add", "negate"] as expected.

EDIT: @Bergi suggests this is more elegant and solves the constructor problem I mentioned. Thank you @Bergi!

```
let operatorNames:Array<string> = ["add", "negate"];
let root:object = Calculator;
for (let operatorFunctionName of operatorNames) {
  switch (operatorFunctionName) {
    case "add":
      root = class AddClass extends root {
        constructor(name) { super(name); }
        add(left:number, right:number) {
          console.log(this.name + " " + (left + right));
        }
      };
      break;
    case "negate":
      root = class NegateClass extends root {
        constructor(name) { super(name); }
        negate(right:number) {
          console.log(this.name + " " + (-right));
        }
      };
      break;
  }
}
return new root("someName") as Calculator;
```

Comment: [Do not use `root = new negatePrototype();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)! Instead, build a class hierarchy, if you must. Start with `root = Calculator`, then do `root = class AddClass extends root { … }` and `root = class NegateClass extends root { … }` instead of the `setPrototypeOf` stuff, and only in the end instantiate `new root("someName")`.

Comment: @Bergi You are absolutely right, your solution is more elegant, solves the problems with my solution, and works like a charm. Thank you! I wish I could mark your comment as the right answer. I updated my answer with your notes.

Comment: @DoomGoober ... How would one achieve with the above approach all of the possible variations and combinations your are talking about in the original question? _"... Calculator with Add() and Subtract(), and many more combos"_ ... like with the above introduced additional `negate`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger You keep adding cases to the switch statement and then change operatorNames to be the combination of methods you want. I have a finite number of methods that can be combined, but the combinations I need are unknown at run time. The key thing I didn't understand was that you could dynamically create a class at runtime using extends. Your solution and Bergi 's solutions both utilize the dynamic usage of "extends" which is the key to the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `decorator` pattern to add functions to instances dynamically. It will be added officially to javascript hopefully, but you can use the fact that instances are objects to create a decorator pattern. EDIT changed the code to use Object.Assign

```
class Calculator {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Calculator"
  }
}

// decorator to create a super calculator that can add
const superCalculator = (calculator) => {
  const add = (a,b) => a+b
  return Object.assign(calculator, {name: "Super Calculator", add})
}

const simpleCalc = new Calculator();
const superCalc = superCalculator(new Calculator());

console.log(simpleCalc.name)
console.log(superCalc.name)
console.log(simpleCalc.add(3,4))  // simple calculator can not add 
console.log(superCalc.add(3,4))   // super calculator can do it
```

Comment: The decorators that will come to JS will work completely different though, they are not meant to decorate objects. You are using the *decorator pattern*, which is totally fine, but a different concept.

Comment: You should not use a `class` here if you are going to use spread syntax. `superCalc instanceof Calculator` will be `false`, since you lost the prototype. Either start with a simpler `const simpleCalc = {name: "Calculator"}`, or use `return Object.assign(calculator, {name: "Super Calculator", add})` in the decorator (which will however modify `simpleCalc` and make `superCalc` identical to it).

Comment: Thanks, I changed the answer to use `Object.assign`. Passing a new instance prevents both calculators becoming the same.

Comment: The above solution burns down to augmenting an object (here a `Calculator` instance) directly with an object-based mixin via `Object.assign`. With this approach all the OP's operator methods would be own properties of any such `Calculator` instance. The OP's `prototype` based reflection tool would be obsolete.

Comment: OK, so we need multiple instances of the same calculator class to have different methods, but also to have the original prototype contain those methods? Maybe we can use `setPrototype` to create copies of the calculator prototype chain, and then use `calculator.constructor.prototype.add = ...`.

Comment: @Kokodoko ... or one utilizes class syntax for subclassing like the OP does practice too at whom's own answer in order to not having to directly manipulate the prototype chain.

Comment: But the problem with `extends` and also with typescripts `@decorator` is that you can't do it dynamically. If the design goal is to be able to create tons of different variations of classes, the code architecture should represent that. Currently we're jumping through hoops because the reflection tool can't be changed. It seems counterproductive.

Comment: @Kokodoko Yes, I apologize that my use case is truly bizarre, largely because of the hoops caused by the reflection tool which can't be changed. My case is highly specific and the requirements force inelegant solutions.